# Construction of an automorphism of elementary abelian p-group of order $p^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be an elementary abelian p-group of order $p^{2}$. Let $g$, $h$ be two non-trivial elements of $G$. I want to construct an automorphism $\phi\in Aut(G)$ such that $\phi(h)=g$, which is equivalently to give an invertible matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a _{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}%
\end{array}%
\right)\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ such that  $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a _{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}%
\end{array}%
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b %
\end{array}%
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a' \\
b' %
\end{array}%
\right) $$

for $h=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b %
\end{array}%
\right) $ and $g=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a' \\
b' %
\end{array}%
\right) $.

But I don't know what to do next to find $(a_{ij})_{1\leq i, j\leq2}$.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: This is not possible if one of $g,h$ is the identity and the other is not. Otherwise you just solve the equations.

Comment: Thank you, if I understand, the equation have a solution if g and h are two non-trivial elements.

Comment: A possibly simpler way to look at is the following. View $G$ additively, so as a 2-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_p$. When both $g$ and $h$ are non-zero, they can be expanded to vector space bases of $G$: $\{g_1,g_2\}$ and $\{h_1,h_2\}$ with $g=g_1$, $h=h_1$.The linear transformation $T:G\to G$ defined by $T(g_i)=h_i$, $i=1,2$, is one of the automorphisms you are looking for. There will be many such automorphisms, one for each choice of $h_2$.